# Question on Closed Continuous Onto Map with $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ having compact boundary for all $Y$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space. $Y$ a topological space, and $f:X\to Y$ be continuous, closed, and onto.
Also, suppose that for all $y\in Y$, $F_y = f^{-1}(\{y\})$ has compact boundary.

Let $\partial A$ be the boundary of $A$, $A^c$ be complement of $A$,  and

1. $W_{yn} = \{x\in X:d(x,\partial F_y)<\frac{1}{n}\}$
2. $V_{yn} = W_{yn}\cup \text{Int}F_y$
3. $U_{yn} = f(V_{yn}) = (f(W^c_{yn}))^c$

Then, prove that $\forall n, \exists m>n$ such that $U_{xm}\cap U_{ym}\neq\phi \implies U_{xm} \subseteq U_{yn}$

**My Attempt:** I tried to prove by contraposition.

If $U_{xm} \not\subseteq U_{yn}$ $\forall m>n$ for some $n$, then $(f(W^c_{xm}))^c \not\subseteq (f(W^c_{yn}))^c \implies W_{xm} \not\subseteq W_{yn}$

Thus, there exists $z_0\in X$ such that $d(z_0,\partial F_x)<\frac{1}{m}$, but $d(z_0,\partial F_y)\geq \frac{1}{n}$

Also,  $U_{xm}\cap U_{ym} =\phi \implies W_{xm}\cap W_{ym} = \phi$.

So, in order to show $U_{xm}\cap U_{ym} =\phi$, we need to show that for all $z\in W_{ym}$, $z\not\in W_{xm}$,

That is, $d(z,\partial F_y)<\frac{1}{m}\implies d(z,\partial F_x)\not<\frac{1}{m}$

This last step is where I'm stuck. Any help will be appreciated!